# Django REST get category list with their products list

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two django model named Category and Product. In Category model has "is_featured" boolean field. I need category list in JSON format where is_featured=true and the list of products. The models are like following.

```
from django.db import models

    class Category(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, null=False)
        is_featured=models.BooleanField(default=False)
        parent=models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Product(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, null=False)
        category=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        uom=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        price=models.FloatField()

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.name, self.category.name, self.price, self.uom)
```

My expected category list (is_featured=true) result will be look like following.

```
{  
  "id":1,
  "name":"Foods",
  "products":[  
     {  
        "id":2,
        "name":"Chicken Fri",
        "price":80
     },
     {  
        "id":4,
        "name":"Tomato Salad",
        "price":20
     }
  ]
},
{  
  "id":3,
  "name":"Vegitable",
  "products":[  
     {  
        "id":3,
        "name":"Potato",
        "price":20
     },
     {  
        "id":6,
        "name":"Bean",
        "price":55
     }
  ]
}
```

I am beginner in django. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Can you show an example of a `serializer` you have tried?

Comment: I don't know the initial approach to solve it yet. It would be also help for me that how can I start.

Comment: This should help: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships